# Latex keeps putting me in math mode for a list that should not be in math mode

Tags: math-mode, errors, text

I am setting up latex for my conlang. Above this point, I have tables that include \textyogh with no issues. However, in a list later on, I have the line (in context):

```
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T3,OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa}

...

begin{itemize}
\item K\textyogh{}ui\gg (k-zh-oi-k\^h)
end{itemize}
```

And Papeeria keeps adding a $ to this line, and then getting angry about the rest not being math. It's not the dashes, as I have them earlier in the list, and I used the dash so it wouldn't worry about the caret.

How can I make it stop thinking it needs to be in math mode?

Comment: `\gg` is *much greater than*, and it's math mode only.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I had defined the other aspirated plosives as /bb and /dd because the others were taken, so I forgot that for that one I had to stick with /kk.